# Constraint On Binary Variable Not Always Holding in Gekko

Tags: python, nonlinear-optimization, gekko

I am creating a non-linear program in Python using the Gekko package. The program includes a constraint of the form:

```
m.Equation(i <= M*q)
```

where `i` is a decision variable, `M` is a large constant (larger than the max possible value of 'i'), and `q` is a binary decision variable that must be forced to 1 if `i` is greater than 0.

The issue is that this constraint doesn't always hold depending on the values of `i` and `M`. For example, if `i` is 100 and `M` is set to 10,000, then `q` becomes 1.

However, if `i` is 100 and `M` is set to 100,000, then `q` remains 0, therefore violating the constraint.

This is problematic because `i` can take on values between 0 and 1,000,000, and I need this constraint to always hold, regardless of the value of `i`.

I've tried using 'm.if3()' but that just led to no answer being found.

Comment: In the end I did not manage to fix this issue. Instead I wrote exactly the same program in Gurobi and it worked there.

Comment: Gurobi is an excellent choice, especially if your problem is Mixed Integer Linear Programming (MILP). The APOPT solver can handle Mixed Integer Nonlinear Programming and Gekko solves algebraic and differential equation problems. It is best to use the simplest solution that is most specific to your problem. MILP solvers are typically more efficient at solving these types of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the integer tolerance `minlp_integer_tol` to fix the problem. The `APOPT` solver considers `0.01` an integer value unless the tolerance is changed to a more stringent value such as `1.0e-6`.

```py
m = GEKKO(remote=True,server='https://byu.apmonitor.com')
# multiple options as one list
m.solver_options = ['minlp_gap_tol 1.0e-3',\
                    'minlp_integer_tol 1.0e-6']
m.options.solver = 1
```

Also check that the `APOPT` solver is selected with `m.options.SOLVER=1`. The default is to use the `IPOPT` solver that does not enforce integer variables.